# Почему только статические методы?

Tags: c#

Да, в C# очень обширная библиотека. Но почему то многие методы только статические. А хотелось бы ООП. А так, это же функциональщина получается.
Взать тот же метод ForEach для массивов. Не применяется он к экземпляру
класса. Пробовал сделать такую обёртку:

```
class Arr:Array
{
    public void forEach(Action act)
        {Array.ForEach(this,act);}

}
```

Выдаётся ошибка, что от System.Array нельзя наследоваться.
Может как то можно прилепить к массиву такой интерфейс
с минимумом кода?

Comment: это называется [метод расширения](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods): `public static void ForEach<T>(this T[] arr, Action act)`

Comment: Вы путаете функциональное и процедурное программирование.

Comment: @VladD, функции есть - значит функциональное :)

Comment: @Grundy: Ну тогда есть класс Array — значит, ООП!

Comment: Скорее всего это наследие, так как появилось до Linq и прочей функциональщины в C# 3.0, а менять ничего не стали в угоду совместимости

Comment: @Андрей NOP неужели и впраду дело в совместимости?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Напишите метод расширения:

```
static class ArrayExt
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this T[] source, Action<T> action)
    {
        Array.ForEach(source, action);
    }
}
```

Использовать можно, например, так:

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 10 };
arr.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: А метод не перестал быть статическим... Называется поменяли шило на мыло "Array.ForEach(arr, Console.WriteLine)" --> "arr.ForEach(Console.WriteLine)"

Comment: @rotabor, ну таким образом можно сделать код более лаконичным и читабельным. Конкретно этот пример не очень хорош может быть, но в целом, например, есть даже паттерн билдер, который позволяет писать такие цепочки вызовов. Сравните: `Array.ForEach(someLongExpressionThatReturnsArray(), Console.WriteLine)` и `someLongExpressionThatReturnsArray().ForEach(Console.WriteLine)`. Во втором случае мы просто читаем слева направо без необходимости возвращаться к началу чтобы понять что происходит. Но в целом я бы просто нормальный цикл написал бы скорее всего

Answer (score -2):

На этот вопрос "Почему только статические методы?" ответа не дали.

Почему у класса Array много статических методов? Потому, что хотя к массивам и есть объектный доступ, но они несколько отличаются от других объектов. Всё таки, массив - это одна из классических машинно-ориентированных структур данных, и компилятор предоставляет доступ к этой структуре данных через объектную обёртку. Аналогично, например, Enum.

Вообще, наличие статических членов может быть вызвано рядом обстоятельств. Вот некоторые из них:

1. Члены, которые несут информацию о каких-то общих ограничениях для класса, например Array.MaxLength.
2. Члены, которые предоставляют какую-то общесистемную информацию, например DateTime.Now.
3. Члены, которые могут быть применены для объектов со значением null, например String.IsNullOrEmpty.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146603/discussion-on-answer-by-rotabor----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.